# Получить URL всплывающего окна

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте, открываю всплавающее окно с каким-то контентом,

```
window.open();
```

нажимаю подтверждение каких-то данных, происходит редирект и в строке URL возвращаются GET данные

Вопрос в том, можно ли каким-то образом вытащить GET данные измененного URL этого самого дочернего окна, например, при закрытии этого самого окна, то есть

```
window.close();
```

или как-нибудь по-другому, вообще возможно сделать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Похожая ситуация с авторизацией ВКонтакте: открывается их адрес, даются разрешения и происходит редирект на адрес, с приписанным в хэше кодом авторизации.

Получить его можно только, если редирект был на ваш домен, вашу страницу — вашим же JavaScript'ом читается window.location

В варианте, когда финальная страница не в вашем домене, скриптами с вашего сайта данные никак не достать — это часть технологии [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (кросс-доменного доступа к общим ресурсам).

Comment: Да, именно с VK API  я и парюсь. Проблема в том, что если указывать редирект на свой сайт - то нет доступа к добавлению, редактированию и удалению постов и пр. Если указать редирект на VK - то все доступы открываются, но проблема в том, что token  в этом случаю можно получить только вручную и автоматизировать этот процесс в браузере никак не получается. Видимо вы правы - никак не достать token

Comment: Для авторизации приложения как Standalone придётся либо действительно писать такое приложение, например, как Chrome App. Либо беспросветно ламерски писать юзеру: «скопируйте адресную строку и вставьте её в эту форму» – видел, некоторые так делают. Минус ещё и в том, что не сработает с далёкого сервера, ВК внезапно попросит капчу, если регион ip с которого запрашивали токен, и откуда его пытаются использовать, далеки друг от друга.

Comment: Способ ламерски писать юзеру я, конечно же, исключаю...  
Так что же, получается, что вообще никак нельзя сделать авторизацию с полными правами доступа на собственном сайте?   
Тут же возникает вопрос: "А ЗАЧЕМ" тогда вообще нужна эта авторизация?, - если методы, которые доступны, они и без токена доступны.

Comment: «Зачем?» – скажем, что-то узнать про закрытую группу можно только с токеном юзера, который туда доступ имеет.

Авторизацию с полными правами можно. Есть один хак: нужно авторизовывать как Standalone, и указывать старую версию API, 3.x — и при последующих запросах тоже — тогда, во всяком случае, не пересправшивает капчу и прочие переподтверждения.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, @sergiks, буду пробовать!
____
Видимо, такой хак уже не работает, попробовал - не получается...

Answer (score 0):

Разбирай window.location во всплывающем окне и отправляй на сервер, например.
Вот первое решение, которое нашлось http://akonan.ru/index.php?id=6

```
function get(n){  
  a=window.location.toString();  
  a="&"+a.substring(a.indexOf("?")+1); 
  p=a.indexOf("&"+n+"=");  
  a=p==-1?'':a.substring(p+n.length+2);  
  return a.indexOf("&")>=0?a.substring(0,a.indexOf("&")):a;
}
```

Comment: Да, и еще. Забыл сказать, что доступа к данным всплывающего окна у меня нет, то есть в окне открывается сторонний сайт.

Comment: Делай _свое_ всплывающее окно. В него Iframe с нужным сайтом и JS для отслеживания событий и передачи данных. При изменении адреса Iframe передавай изменившийся адрес на родительскую(opener) страницу и закрывай всплывающую.

Comment: Таким образом я мог бы обойтись и без всплывающего окна, просто вставить фрейм в тело документа и загрузить в него сторонний сайт, но проблема в том, что я не нашел способа вытащить строку URL из этого самого фрейма(((

Comment: Посмотри здесь http://buznik.net/j/212/facebook-like-box-s-dinamicheskoy-shirinoy-jquery/

Ну и вообще iframe.contentWindow.location

Comment: Нет, это не то...

Comment: iframe.contentWindow.location не то?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!